# Understanding Mypy Error Reporting with Default `--follow-imports=normal`

Tags: python, mypy

I'm currently working with `mypy` for type checking in a Python project and have encountered a behavior that I'd like to understand better regarding how `mypy` reports errors, especially under the default `--follow-imports=normal` setting.

Consider a scenario where I have three files:

- `foo.py` (which is the main file I'm checking)
- `a.py` (imported by `foo.py`)
- `b.py` (also imported by `foo.py`)

When I run `mypy` to check `foo.py`, I get an output that indicates errors spread across all three files (e.g., "Found 25 errors in 3 files (checked 1 source file)"). My understanding is that mypy, under `--follow-imports=normal`, should primarily report errors in the file explicitly being checked (`foo.py` in this case), and only include errors from the imported files (`a.py` and `b.py`) if they directly affect the type correctness of `foo.py`.

However, I'm unclear on the following points:

1. Does `mypy` report all errors from `a.py` and `b.py` regardless of whether they directly impact `foo.py`?
2. Or does it only report errors from `a.py` and `b.py` that have a direct consequence on the type safety of `foo.py`?

The reason I am asking is I am facing some peculiar errors when running a `mypy` check on Github actions (for a public repo):

```bash
mypy --follow-imports=normal foo.py
```

```bash
Found 25 errors in 3 files (checked 1 source file)
```

I have read the `mypy` documentation:

- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html
- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/existing_code.html

but still isn't clear.

Comment: You will see all errors from all imported files that belong to your package, not only those "related to foo.py" - the latter is too vague to define strictly.